# How open 2 links in new tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I use this code to open 2 sites in new tabs in browser

```
    $("#mylink").on('click', '#one', function () {
    window.open('registration.php', '_blank');
    window.open('readme.php', '_blank');
```

but when I click on link, second link has bet blocked as popup.
How to open 2 sites contemporaneously?

P.S. If this is not possible, how open second link in current browser tab?

Comment: Pop up blockers will block it... If it is actually a link you are clicking, why is it not opening up one of the tabs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `_self` as parameter to open in the same window. i.e.

```
$("#mylink").on('click', '#one', function () {
    window.open('registration.php', '_blank');
    window.open('readme.php', '_self');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to "unblock" it as a popup, as far as I know. It would be easier to just give 2 links.